# collision detection in javascript game?

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

My Map array ;;

```
map[0] = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
map[1] = [0,1,0,1,0,1]
map[2] = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
map[3] = [1,0,1,0,1,0]
map[4] = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
map[5] = [0,1,0,1,0,1]
```

1= Hurdle
0 = Nothing

i've to detect collision detection b/w player and hurdles in map.

player.x & player.y is the reference from left top .
Each hurdle is 40px of width and length .

i need a roughly concept not codes

Comment: what's wrong with `map[player.y][player.x]` ?

Comment: 0 represents 40px Empty place , 1 = 40 px box.. what if player is at player.x < 40 or player.y<40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to normalize player position to the collision map unit as player position is in `px` units and your collision map is in `array index` units and then test if the field the player tries to enter is not a hurdle.

```
function normalizePosition(entity){
    return { 
        x: Math.ceil(entity.pos.x / TILE_WIDTH), 
        y: Math.ceil(entity.pos.y / TILE_HEIGHT) 
    }
}
```

Normalize position will give you entity coordinates on the collision map and next you have to test the actual collision to see what kind of tile is the entity entering

```
function mapCollision(entity, map){
    var mapCoords = normalizePosition(entity),
        tileType = map[mapCoords.y][mapCoords.x];
    return tileType;
}
```

It will return the code of tile type on the map for player normalized position in case you wanted to have there different things then just blocks like some kind of slowing down traps or whatever other bear pits. You could then handle different cases where zero would default to accepts player entering the tile.

Hope I didn't tell to much :)

Good luck with your game and if you'll remember I'd be happy if you'd share the effects with me when its done :)

Tom

**Update**

I made a simple example for better interpretation purpose:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/qFCyn/1/

Comment: well, i'm totally beginner .... writing my first program after a simple web in HTML

Comment: games are definitely a good way to learn some more advanced javascript concepts - there's tons of things you'll get stuck on but when you get past these walls its one of the most rewarding things to do I think. I recommend you reading some books for more mature languages when it comes to game developement to get a better idea of game engine architecture and some standard problem solving patterns. Learning some game dev in C++/obj-c have pushed my ability to code them in javascript A LOT

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var BLOCK_SIZE = 40; // 40px * 40px blocks
var hurdle = map[player.y/BLOCK_SIZE][player.x/BLOCK_SIZE]
if(hurdle) {
    // stuff
} else {
    // other stuff
}
```