# Getting image pixel data from a canvas sprite

Tags: javascript, canvas, sprite

I'm trying to implement pixel perfect collision detection in my canvas game, however I can't seem to get the pixel information from my sprites.

I need the x and y values for each pixel of the sprite, and from what I've read I use the `getImageData()` method to do that.

However, this doesn't work:

```
this.sprite = new Image();
this.sprite.src = 'img/player.png';
console.log(this.sprite.getImageData());
```

Am I maybe using the wrong type of sprite? Because I get this error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method
>   'getImageData'

Comment: `getImageData()` is a method for canvas, not images. What do you mean by "to get the pixel information from my sprites" ?

Comment: Box detection is not that difficult - pixel-shape-based detection is probably going to be pretty process-intensive.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017541/javascript-canvas-collision-detection and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871669/collision-detection-in-javascript-game

Comment: Ah, I thought it might be. What I mean by that is I want to know the x and y co-ordinate on the canvas for every pixel that's in my sprite. @Diodeus, not as much as you think. Although it can be with a lot of objects, I only have a few sprites on the canvas at a time. Also, box-detection isn't good enough for this purpose as the sprites aren't rectangular.

Answer (score 5):

**Here’s how to use a sprite’s pixel data to do pixel-perfect hit-testing**

First, draw your sprite normally on your visible canvas.

[image]

Create a **red-masked copy** of the sprite on a hidden canvas.  This copy is the exact size as the sprite but contains **only** transparent or red pixels.

[image]

Track the visible sprite’s bounding box.  When the bounding box is clicked calculate the X/Y of the mouseclick **in relation to the sprite’s bounding box** (not in relation to the canvas).

Then, refer to the red-masked sprite and see if the corresponding pixel at that X/Y is red or transparent.  If the pixel is red, you have a pixel-perfect hit.  If the pixel is transparent, no hit.

In this illustration, assume the blue dots are the X/Y click position.  Since the corresponding X/Y pixel in the red-masked canvas is “red”, this is a HIT.

[image]

Here is code to create a red-masked sprite.   I don’t show the code for hit-testing here, but if you try and can’t code the hit-test, I’ll take the time to code up the hit-testing too.

Important note:  to get this code to run, you must avoid the cross-domain security restriction.  Be sure your image source is on your local domain, otherwise you will run into a **cross domain security violation** and the masking image will not be drawn…So you can't do this for your sprite source: http://otherDomain.com/picture.jpg!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
    canvas{border:1px solid blue;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

        var img=new Image();
        img.onload=function(){
          ctx.drawImage(this,100,25);

          // make a red-masked copy of just the sprite
          // on a separate canvas
          var canvasCopy=document.getElementById("canvasCopy");
          var ctxCopy=canvasCopy.getContext("2d");
          canvasCopy.width=this.width;
          canvasCopy.height=this.height;
          ctxCopy.drawImage(img,0,0);

          // make a red-masked copy of the sprite on a separate canvas
          var imgData=ctxCopy.getImageData(0,0,c.width,c.height);
          for (var i=0;i<imgData.data.length;i+=4)
            {
                if(imgData.data[i+3]>0){
                    imgData.data[i]=255;
                    imgData.data[i+1]=0;
                    imgData.data[i+2]=0;
                    imgData.data[i+3]=255;
                }
            }
          ctxCopy.putImageData(imgData,0,0);         

        }
        img.src = "houseIcon.png";

    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Original sprite drawn on canvas at XY:100/25</p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
    <p>Red-masked on canvas used for hit-testing</p>
    <canvas id="canvasCopy" width="300" height="300"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

**To do pixel-perfect collision testing between 2 sprites, you would:**

Create a red-masked canvas for both sprite#1 and sprite#2.

First test if the bounding boxes of the 2 sprites are colliding.  If the bounding boxes are not colliding, the 2 sprites are not colliding, so you can stop the hit-test here.

If the 2 sprites are *possibly* colliding using the bounding boxes test, create a third canvas for the collision test.

You’re going to use canvas’s compositing method to test for a collision between sprite#1 and sprite#2 by drawing both sprite#1 and sprite#2 onto the third canvas.  Using compositing, only the **COLLIDING** pixels of the 2 sprites will be drawn on the third canvas.

Here’s how Compositing with “destination-in” works:  The existing canvas content is kept where both the new shape (sprite#2) and existing shape (sprite#1) content overlap. Everything else is made transparent.

So…

Draw sprite#1 **in its transformed state** into the third canvas (transforms could be move, rotate, scale, skew--anything!).

Set the globalCompositeOperation to destination-in.

```
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
```

Draw sprite#2 **in its transformed state** into the third canvas.

After this draw, the third canvas contains **only the colliding portions of sprite#1 and sprite#2**

Test each pixel in the third canvas for non-transparent pixels.  If you find any non-transparent pixels, the 2 sprites ARE COLLIDING.

Depending on what action you want to take upon collision, you might just bail out when you find the first colliding pixel.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @markE. One question though, if we are going to use 'destination-in', why do we need to red mask the sprite? The non-overlapping pixels aren't going to be drawn anyway, and then we continue searching for non-transparent pixels.